# How to get JPanel equal width and height

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I found the following code from http://www.java-forums.org/new-java/7995-how-plot-graph-java-given-samples.html.

I don't understand why w = getWidth() and h = getHeight() are not equal. And how to make them equal to each other?

Thanks

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class GraphingData extends JPanel {
 int[] data = {
     21, 14, 18, 03, 86, 88, 74, 87, 54, 77,
     61, 55, 48, 60, 49, 36, 38, 27, 20, 18
 };
 final int PAD = 20;

protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
    g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                        RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    int w = getWidth();
    int h = getHeight();
    // Draw ordinate.
    g2.draw(new Line2D.Double(PAD, PAD, PAD, h-PAD));
    // Draw abcissa.
    g2.draw(new Line2D.Double(PAD, h-PAD, w-PAD, h-PAD));
    double xInc = (double)(w - 2*PAD)/(data.length-1);
    double scale = (double)(h - 2*PAD)/getMax();
    // Mark data points.
    g2.setPaint(Color.red);
    for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        double x = PAD + i*xInc;
        double y = h - PAD - scale*data[i];
        g2.fill(new Ellipse2D.Double(x-2, y-2, 4, 4));
    }
}

private int getMax() {
    int max = -Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        if(data[i] > max)
            max = data[i];
    }
    return max;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.add(new GraphingData());
    f.setSize(400,400);
    f.setLocation(200,200);
    f.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be under the assumption that the size of frame is the size of the viewable content area.

A frame is made up of the content AND frame decorations.  So on my system, a frame of 400x400, results in a content viewable area of 384x362

[image: Frame Size]

The first thing you should do is get rid of `f.setSize()`, it is unreliable as the viewable content area it creates will be different for each system your program runs on.  Instead, you should be using `f.pack()`, which uses the frame contents to determine the size of the window (so that the viewable content area is given precedence).

Next, in you `GraphingData` class, you will need to override `getPreferredSize` and return the preferred size of the panel you would like to use.

```
@Override
public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
    return new Dimension(400, 400);
}
```

This will allow (some) layout managers to make better decisions about how best to present your component.