# Only Title bar shows, the JFrame is not showing

Tags: java, swing, canvas, jframe

The title bar only shows after I click run, the frame is not working....
Here is my code
I have no ideas what is going on! 
Can someone help me?

```
import java.awt.Canvas;
import javax.swing.JFrame;


public class Display extends Canvas implements Runnable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public static final int WIDTH = 800;
    public static final int HEIGH = 600;
    public static String TITLE = "3D Game";

    private Thread thread;
    private boolean running = false;
    private void start(){
        if(running) return;
        running = true;
        thread = new Thread();
        thread.start();

        System.out.println("Working");
    }

    private void stop(){
        if(!running)
            return;
        running = false;
        try{
        thread.join();
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(0);
    }   
    }
    public void run(){
        while(running){

        }
    }



    public static void main(String[] args){

        Display game = new Display();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(game);
        //frame.pack();
        frame.setTitle(TITLE);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(WIDTH,HEIGHT);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        game.start();

    }


}
```

Comment: You `while-loop` is running free, meaning that it will consume all the CPU cycles and bring your UI to a standstill (as the UI thread is not getting a chance to  run)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the difference between

```
public static final int HEIGH = 600;
```

and

```
frame.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
```

`Canvas` indirectly defines two `public static` fields called `WIDTH` and `HEIGHT` set to `1` and `2` respectively

A better solution would be to override `Canvas`s `getPreferredSize` method and return the preferred size you want...

```
@Override
public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
    return new Dimension(800, 600);
}
```

The you can just use pack

```
Display game = new Display();
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.add(game);
frame.pack();
frame.setTitle(TITLE);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
frame.setResizable(false);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

A word or warning against using `setSize` on a top level container.  A window normally contains frame decorations, these are included WITHIN the windows bounds. If you use `setSize`, you are reducing the content area by the amount of window decorations, which will result in a smaller then expected size.  Instead, you should override the `getPreferredSize` method of your main container and call `pack`. This allows the window to "pack" itself around the content, but leave space for the frame decorations, preserving the space you have requested.

[image: FrameSetup]

You can also have a look at:

- [How to get JPanel equal width and height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22185774/how-to-get-jpanel-equal-width-and-height/22185900#22185900)
- [How to get the EXACT middle of a screen, even when re-sized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13457237/how-to-get-the-exact-middle-of-a-screen-even-when-re-sized/13460914#13460914)
- [Graphics rendering in title bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13313084/graphics-rendering-in-title-bar/13316131#13316131)
- [How can I set in the midst?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13734069/how-can-i-set-in-the-midst/13734319#13734319)

For more details

Answer (score 0):

You have made a typo when declaring the static height variable, You have declared it as "**HEIGH**" but in the JFrame you have used the word "**HEIGHT**"

```
public static final int HEIGH = 600;

frame.setSize(WIDTH,HEIGHT);
```

So change the variable to **HEIGHT** and it should work